# Page keep reloading and the changed image doesn't stay

Tags: javascript, reload

I wrote javascript that suppose to change the image when number 1-5 is entered in the input between 1-5, and give alert else; both if/then/else and switch.

But when I input the number, it changes briefly and the pages seems to reload. If else is put in, then the alert shows as expected. Not sure why. Can someone please take a look? any feedback would be welcome.

```js
/*
Pseudo Code: 
Load page.
Submit the number to either input for If/Then or Switch.
Check if the number is between 1-5.
If the number is between 1-5, change the image to match that number. 
If the number is not 1-5 or text, display alert. 
End program.
*/

//function for changing if/then statements from 1-5

function ifThenNumber() {

  var ifThenInput = document.getElementById("userIfInput").value;

  if (ifThenInput == 1)
    document.getElementById("ifThenImage").src = "./number-images/one.gif";
  else if (ifThenInput == 2)
    document.getElementById("ifThenImage").src = "./number-images/two.gif";
  else if (ifThenInput == 3)
    document.getElementById("ifThenImage").src = "./number-images/three.gif";
  else if (ifThenInput == 4)
    document.getElementById("ifThenImage").src = "./number-images/four.gif";
  else if (ifThenInput == 5)
    document.getElementById("ifThenImage").src = "./number-images/five.gif";
  else alert("Please put a number between 1-5");

} // end function ifThenNumber

//function for changing switch statements from 1-5

function switchNumber() {
  var switchInput = document.getElementById("userSwitchInput").value;

  switch (switchInput) {
    case "1":
      document.getElementById("switchImage").src = "./number-images/one.gif";
      break;
    case "2":
      document.getElementById("switchImage").src = "./number-images/two.gif";
      break;
    case "3":
      document.getElementById("switchImage").src = "./number-images/three.gif";
      break;
    case "4":
      document.getElementById("switchImage").src = "./number-images/four.gif";
      break;
    case "5":
      document.getElementById("switchImage").src = "./number-images/five.gif";
      break;
    default:
      alert("Please put a number between 1-5");
  } //end switch (switchInput)
} // end function switchImage
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Lesson 4</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="numberStatement">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <th> If/Then/Else </th>
               <th> Switch </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  <!--image with if/then/else statement--> 
                  <img id="ifThenImage" src="./number-images/zero.gif" />
               </th>
               <th>
                  <!--image with switch statement--> 
                  <img id="switchImage" src="./number-images/zero.gif" />
               </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <!--instruction for user-->
               <th> Enter number from 1 - 5 </th>
               <th> Enter number from 1 - 5 </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <!--input that user can enter-->
               <th> 
                  <input type="text" name="userIfInput" id="userIfInput" size="20" /> 
               </th>
               <th>
                  <input type="text" name="userSwitchInput" id="userSwitchInput" size="20" />
               </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <!--button to submitt the information-->
               <th> 
                  <button onclick="ifThenNumber()" >Submit</button>
               </th>
               <th>
                  <button onclick="switchNumber()" >Submit</button>
               </th>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [prevent default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of submit button which is send form data and reload page:

```
function ifThenNumber(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // all your logic here
}
```

Comment: Seems like this didn't fix the issue.. keep when I added this event, the default stopped working, but there was no change when entering in number 1-5 either.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! It's due to the  tag covering the whole table instead of just the !